# Find the place of decimal point in decimal number

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to find place of  decimal point  in a decimal number in SQL Server using sql query

example:

```
123567.89
```

output:7

Comment: [CHARINDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select charindex('.', cast(123567.89 as varchar))
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/23847)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @T decimal(38,1) = 1234567890123456789012345678901234567.1;
select charindex('.', cast(@T as varchar(40)));
```

If only varchar is used, the size is 30 by default; therefore, it'd fail. In addition to that, if this was in a computed column and varchar is used, the size is 1 by default.

40 = 38 + 'decimal point' plus 'sign'

```
--select charindex('.', cast(@T as varchar)); -- Uncomment and it'll fail
```